# Cannot debug flask with vscode after update

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I recently updated vscode (Version 1.27.1 (1.27.1) and now I cannot debug my flask application.

I put a breakpoint in one of my route handlers and instead of stopping there it stops in `serving.py` in the function `serve_forever` on line 612.

I was able to reproduce this by creating a simple app from the Flask website.  Adding a breakpoint on `return "Hello World!"` and entering `localhost:5000` in a browser.  The launch configuration is the default one created by vscode for Flask.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been identified as a bug in the python plugin.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2538#issuecomment-420742493

There is a work around.  Just select the thread in the call stack running your code and you will be fine.